# If $X\in \mathbb{L^1}$, then by DCT, $\int |X|1_{\{X>M\}}dP < \varepsilon$

Tags: measure-theory

If $X\in \mathbb{L^1}$, then by DCT, $\int |X|1_{\{X>M\}}dP < \varepsilon$

This is an exercise I'm trying to figure out.

Since $X$ is integrable, then $|X|$ is integrable and $|X|\in\mathbb{L}^1$.

Suppose $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} X1_{\{X>n\}}=X1_{\{X>M\}}$ for some $M>0$. (Is this correct?)

Since $ |X|1_{\{X>n\}}<|X|1_{\{X>M\}}$ and $|X|$ is integrable,
then 
$$\int|X|1_{\{X>M\}}dP=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int|X| 1_{\{X>n\}}dP=0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple errors here. The step $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X1_{X>n}=X1_{X>M}$ is false. Think about what $1_{X>n}$ means: we are looking at the set on which $X>n$. Something like $X(x)=1/x$ won't satisfy your claim. First show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} X1_{X>n}=0$ almost surely. This will follow by virtue of $X$ being a function (try a by contradiction argument). Next, use the fact that $|X1_{X>n}|\leq |X|$.

Comment: Can I show $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} X1_{X>n}=0$ a.s. by arguing:

Assume $X1_{X>n}\rightarrow L$ where $L\ne 0$.

But $1_{X>n}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Would this be the contradiction? Although usually when I show something holds a.s. I'd have to use Borel Cantelli lemma? Thanks so much!